# jQuery click Iframe body or Iframe object

Tags: jquery

I am trying to click Iframe

```
<iframe id="anvasImageUploader" src="something.php"></iframe>


$('#canvasImageUploader').click(function(){ closeLightbox(false, true, false) });
```

this is my code but not works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `click` event on an `iframe`. If the contents of the iframe are on the same domain, you can bind to the document of that instead:

```
$("#canvasImageUploader").contents().find("body").click(function() {
  parent.closeLightbox(false, true, false);
});
```

Comment: it works once while Iframe will reload, afte reload does not works

Comment: You will need to use the jQuery `on()` function to bind to any dynamically created elements `$("#canvasImageUploader").contents().on("click", "body", function() { ... });`

Comment: Are you reloading the iframe yourself? Then you need to rebind the click handler every time you reload the iframe